# How can I love a Creator who causes me pain and grief?

Tags: qadar

This question is somewhat related to the Problem of Evil. To start off, I do understand that we're slaves of the Creator and He can do whatever He wishes with us.

1. He can bless a couple with a child and then take the child away from the couple as well. Thereby causing the couple considerable amount of grief and pain.
2. He is the one who grants political power to humans. He grants power to tyrants who slaughter innocents and thereby causing immense grief and pain.
3. He is the one Who gives sustenance and when He likes it, takes it away as well. Thereby causing grief and pain to one who is in such a position.

I will restate that we're His slaves and He's our master and can do whatever He wishes.

What I have a hard time understanding is that we're supposed to love Him as well. I just cannot bring myself to do that. 
- How can I love someone who causes me pain and grief
- How can I love someone who is only happy if I am writhing in pain and grief

Comment: Please note, according to popular beliefs, the creator will not be happy seeing you in pain, but he will be happy to see you remember him even in pain. So, ask forgiveness for your sins and stay patient. If you don't stay patient now, you will **not** be happy in the after life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The analogies presented by Hamza islam are pretty good. But, I would like to present a couple of verses which I hope would help you understand, without *pain*.

> *For his sake there are angels following one another, before him and behind him, who guard him by Allah's commandment; surely **Allah does not change the condition of a people until they change their own condition**; and when Allah intends evil to a people, there is no averting it, and besides Him they have no protector. [Qur'an [13:11]](http://corpus.quran.com/translation.jsp?chapter=13&verse=11)*

To fully understand the picture, you need to know the distinction between punishment and trials.

Here is an excellent article in [IslamQA](http://islamqa.info/en/324) on the topic "Difference Between Punishments and Trials", which is somewhat related to this question.

If you believe the undeniable facts that good people go to paradise and bad go to hell, then, you must realize, although it is hazy, that the Creator *loves* you, and that is why he is causing you to suffer pain and grief, and he is *happy*, because he might later think of averting from throwing you in hell fire, because you already [suffered for your mistakes](http://corpus.quran.com/translation.jsp?chapter=42&verse=30).

> *The Prophet (peace be upon him) said: A Muslim male or female, remains subject to trials (in this world) in respect of self, children and property till he or she faces Allah, the Exalted, (on the Day of Judgment) in a state in which all his or her sins have been remitted. [Al-Tirmidhi Hadith](http://www.alim.org/library/hadith/TIR/12)*

And also note that, Allah doesn't cause a person bear more than what he can bear. So, be [patient](http://quran.com/22/34-35).

> *On no soul doth Allah Place a burden greater than it can bear. It gets every good that it earns, and it suffers every ill that it earns. (Pray:) "Our Lord! Condemn us not if we forget or fall into error; our Lord! Lay not on us a burden Like that which Thou didst lay on those before us; **Our Lord! Lay not on us a burden greater than we have strength to bear.** Blot out our sins, and grant us forgiveness. Have mercy on us. Thou art our Protector; Help us against those who stand against faith. [Qur'an [2:286]](http://corpus.quran.com/translation.jsp?chapter=2&verse=286)*"

**TL;DR** **If you did something wrong, you deserve punishment in this life, and that's for your welfare. If Allah loves you, he might try you. In both cases, you need to be patient.**

Answer (score 3):

The answer can be understood by very simple example.

Suppose there is a child. he is naughty, he wants to play with fire, but parents stop him, scold him, he doesn't listen, he still wants to grab fire, but then the parents have to beat him (causing immense pain and suffering) why? Only to SAVE the child from Serious harm by giving Small harm. but Child is Immature. he is not knowledgeable enough to understand why parents punished him. but when he grow ,only then he finds it out. Till then, child will have same question/doubt as you have (why god becomes happy by punishing us)

Another analogy can be, During the army or special forces training sessions, how intense psychological and physical pain you go through. why? what is the goal? the goal is that you can become PERFECT and Strong enough to handle any future problems/pain/suffering. 
So all that pain and suffering is for a good cause.

Same is the case with GOD. GOD Gives us pain and suffering not because he Likes it, or be happy with it. but to Teach us lessons of life, to make us Humble, to make us patient, to Teach us who we are and what is purpose of our life and to Test among us that who is best believer.

Imagine there is no pain and no suffering,then who will ever LEARN what patience is? who will ever become strong? who will ever become psychologically strong enough to handle pain of others?

The knowledge given to us is very limited. we never know what is good for us. so God give us precise level of pain (and happiness too) both at perfectly right time

Comment: Well done, dear Hamza. Factually submitting by giving an example would be easier for the reader to get the issue.

Answer (score -4):

Knowledge and understanding is attainable
Without the requirement for pain & suffering to serve as some sort of reinforcement. 
_